# What is purpose of these arm band?

Tags: tropes

In anime, people who in charge sometimes wear armband,

[image]

<sup>from left to right: Haruhi Suzumiya - The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya (Club president), Suzu and Tsuda - Seitokai Yakuindomo (student council), Kuroko - Toaru Kagaku no Railgun (Judgement, Disciplinary Committee), Kamado Ueshita - Mirai Nikki (Director of the orphanage).</sup>

is this arm band have particular name? what is it purpose and how is this originate? Is this related to Japanese culture? I never see someone wearing this in my country.

Comment: from what i understand they show they are in a school club/group like a Student Council/Disciplinary Committee, the 3rd one is Kuroko being in JUDGEMENT which is like a Disciplinary Committee except city wide, not sure if it's a culture thing or not though

Comment: probably relevant: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedArmbandOfLeadership

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arm bands in Japan, usually called as **red armband**, is worn as a method of identification of team/group or organization (more on this at the end)

> The red armband can have a very different connotation in Japanese
>   culture than in that of many other countries. The leader of any group
>   might wear a red armband, usually with the characters for the name of
>   the organisation written on it, as a symbol of his authority. Due to
>   cultural diffusion, the usage of the red armband by leftist political
>   groups has spread to Japan as well.

*[Source](http://www.ehow.co.uk/facts_7431774_red-armband-significance.html)*

The link also has information on how it spread to Japan but that's out of the scope so I'm not including it here.

Known bands from the picture:

[image]

1) Haruhi Suzumiya wears a band that reads [Brigade leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruhi_Suzumiya_(character)#Appearance)

[image]

2) In Ousai (Private Academy featured in Seitokai Yakuindomo) [red armbands](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/SeitokaiYakuindomo) signifies power, not
 leadership—students that enforces rules wear them.

[image]

3) In Toaru Kagaku no Railgun, this band signifies the [Judgement Committee](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Judgment)

Couldn't find information regarding the fourth.

---

Also, personally, in many Japanese Dramas I have seen working people wear such bands like the reporters, journalists, forensics and even the police officers (not red though, it's usually white in black text) so I'm guessing it's a way to tell who's from which organization.

Comment: While the armband Haruhi is wearing in the question does read "Brigade Leader", the one you've included in your answer reads "Super Director" - it's the one she was wearing when they were filming The Adventures of Mikuru.

Comment: @senshin Too bad I don't read Japanese. Thanks for the info. Is the above image correct?

Comment: Yup, that's the "Brigade Leader" armband.